# Is it possible to download sandbox projects with Drush?

Tags: drush

Normally, one can download a module from drupal.org like this:

`drush dl views`

However, this doesn't work for sandbox projects.  Is there an easy way to download them or I am stuck with `git clone`?

Comment: I asked a similar question on Drupal.org and was informed that I dont have to use git: http://drupal.org/node/1576296

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I do believe you're stuck with git for this one. Drush requires the use of a module name, even when fetching with git (`drush dl --package-handler=git_drupalorg`), and sandbox projects don't have module names.

Drush also requires you to download a release of a module. Sandbox projects have no releases. This may also just be by design, since using sandbox modules can be dangerous, and is made difficult on purpose.

You could slightly automate it with a git alias. You could set up something like:

```
git dl-sb username/number project_name
```

This would just do `git clone http://git.drupal.org/sandbox/username/number.git project_name`

You could also write a drush command that would do the same thing, though it would be a weird drush command...

Answer (score 20):

It's possible to download sandbox project with drush using make file.

Here is example.make file:

```
core = 7.x
api = 2
; Sandbox module
projects[range_field][type] = module
projects[range_field][download][type] = git
projects[range_field][download][branch] = "7.x-1.x"
projects[range_field][download][url] = http://git.drupal.org/sandbox/Taran2L/1848632.git
projects[range_field][download][revision] = a1cc04da3c1dd957e6808b7e6a381c5970904863
```

Then you can execute it via:

```
drush make --no-core example.make # optional options are: -y --working-copy --no-gitinfofile --verbose
```

Comment: I'd reccomend always using git syntax for these urls for security.

projects[range_field][download][url] = git.drupal.org/sandbox/Taran2L/1848632.git

Answer (score 1):

The page Jonathan Sibley is refering to (http://drupal.org/node/1576296) says something like:

1. Go to the project page;
2. Follow "Repository viewer" link;
3. Under "Heads" click the "Tree" link of the branch of your likings;
4. Click the "Snapshot" link to download the sandbox module.

Comment: Looks like this doesn't work any more. For example you can check http://cgit.drupalcode.org/sandbox-bjpritch-2411053/tree/ @imeurs