# How to install a module from an archive file with drush?

Tags: drush, installation

To install a module available on drupal.org, I do `drush dl modulename && drush en modulename`. However, when I have module available as an archive file on my local disk instead (`.zip` or `.tar.gz`), how can I still use `drush` to install it?

The archive file could come from [downloading a sandbox project snapshot](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/112808/16305), from a self-developed "custom made" module or similar.

I know I could unpack the module into `sites/all/modules/`, then enable it with `drush en modulename`. But I'm looking for nice scriptable commands to do both these steps with `drush`. (Bit silly, but I like to keep a `drush` workflow.)

Comment: Yes, it's been [answered here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/31492/17837)

Comment: Edited to make clear I want to install from a local archive file, not via git. Still, your link helped.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`drush make`](http://docs.drush.org/en/master/make/) to unpack a module named `your_module` from an archive file, as follows:

1. Create a `modulename.make` file containing:

   ```
   core = 7.x
   api = 2
   ; Install from local module archive file.
   projects[your_module][type] = "module"
   projects[your_module][download][type] = "file"
   projects[your_module][download][url] = "file:///dir/your_module.tar.gz"
   ```
2. While in the Drupal root directory of your site, execute the Makefile and enable your module:

   ```
   drush make --no-core -y your_module.make && drush en -y your_module
   ```

Alternatively, you can script this into one set of commands, using a temporary file instead of a separate Makefile. Again, to be executed while in the Drupal root directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
module="your_module"
makefile=$(mktemp)
echo "Created temp file $makefile"
cat << end-of-makefile >$makefile
  core = 7.x
  api = 2
  projects[$module][type] = "module"
  projects[$module][download][type] = "file"
  projects[$module][download][url] = "file:///dir/file.tar.gz"
end-of-makefile
drush make --no-core -y --verbose $makefile
drush en -y $module
```

(Bash named pipes or bash [process substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22019615) via `<(echo …)` cannot be used here to avoid a temp file. They create streams, which are non-seekable files that `drush make` fails to read from.)

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need to to type `drush dl modulename && drush en modulename` instead you can type `drush en -y modulename` and Drush is intelligent enough to know that you do not have the module and needs to be download it.

Second, if you have a Sandbox you can enable the module `drush en -y modulename` as long you have the module on your `site/all/modules`. If is a sandbox project from Drupal.org you probably would need to download it via git.

Just like the sandbox project as long you have it locally you can enable it via drush.

If you wish to download the module via drush you can find the answer at [Is it possible to download sandbox projects with Drush?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31492/is-it-possible-to-download-sandbox-projects-with-drush)